# Excel VBScript - fill columns with data

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have a spreadsheet with email addresses (column A) I need to write a macro/VBScript function to fill columns B to L with numbers 1 to 11 respectively i.e.

some.user@address.com 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11

Could someone help me achieve this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you ask. This will add the numbers 1-11 to any row that contains data in the first cell.

```
Sub AddNumbers()
LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
    For Each cell In Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LastRow, 1))
        If cell.Text <> "" Then
            For i = 2 To 12
                Cells(cell.Row, i).Select
                ActiveCell.Value = (i - 1)
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not own excel so I'm not sure if this works properly:

```
for i = 0 to rowCount
 Range("A" + i).select
 for j = 1 to 11
  Cells(i,j).Select ' I'm not sure if this line works
  ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = i
 next j
next i
```

Hope this works.